# Why there is no component when projecting a vector on an orthogonal space of another vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

[image]

Based on the above diagram, may I know why there is no component in direction of vector v?

Answer (score 1):

The projection onto the orthogonal space $v^\perp$ of vector $v$ is a linear operator $$\pi_v: V\to V:x\mapsto x_{\perp v}$$
It sends each vector $x$ into its component in the orthogonal space of $v$. That is, each vector $x$ is mapped with some new vector $x_{\perp v}$ from orthogonal space $v^\perp$ of vector $v$.

And by definition, each vector from orthogonal space $v^\perp$ of $v$ has no component in direction of $v$. Hence $x_{\perp v}\cdot v = 0$, as stated in the picture.